# Absolute positioning makes footer disapear

Tags: html, css

Morning all,

The code below is a simplified template for one of my pages just to give you an idea of how it is set out. I am trying to get my footer to stick to the bottom of the container. I tried position relative in the container and position absolute bottom 0px in the footer however the footer disapears.

I googled it however the only answers I seem to be able to find are telling me to do what I have already tried above.

Does anybody have any idea as to what is wrong?

Thanks

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="container" style="width:1000px; height:1000px;  margin-top:0px; border-left:1px solid black; border-right:1px solid black; position:relative;">

<div>
some content here
</div>


<div id="footer" style="height:15px; background-color:red; position:absolute; bottom:0px; ">
</div>


</div><!-- container end -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please indent code you post properly.

Comment: Applying `position: absolute;` to block level elements makes them lose their behaviour of greedily grabbing all the width they can get. Instead, they turn into elements that are just as wide as their content. No content, no width. So your question is solved by rewording your question title to ***Absolute positioning makes footer lose width***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no error in your code, is just that you haven't added `css width` to your `#footer`, even if you don't add width then you still need some content in it then it will works. At present your `#footer` div is empty.

```html
<div id="container" style="width:1000px; height:1000px;  margin-top:0px; position:relative; background:red">

    <div style="background:yellow">
    some content here
    </div>


    <div id="footer" style="width:100%; height:15px; background:pink; position:absolute; bottom:0px; ">
    </div>


</div>
```